# Share Rapidminer process as XML file

Tags: rapidminer

In Rapidminer, I heard that I can save the process into a XML file, and can also copy an outsider XML file(posted by someone on the Web) into my Rapidminer and open it. But I did not find a button or panel from Rapidminer to enable me share process this way. Would you like to let me know how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the RapidMiner Studio GUI go to

View->Show Panel->XML

The XML panel will show up. You can then select the XML and copy so it can be shared with others. You can also paste XML directly into the panel. To make it import, you have to press the validate button (a small, green tick mark at the top left of the XML panel).